# sklearn TtfidfVectorizer stopwords_

Tags: scikit-learn, stop-words, countvectorizer, tfidfvectorizer

Is there a way to get the tf and idf for the stopwords_ attribute of sklearn's TtfidfVectorizer (not stopwords)?

They are already calculated, so the model should have these values, but has anyone ever used them? If not, I guess I have to hack the internal code and get them myself, correct?

**[UPDATE]**

For anyone who might end up on this question, as an update, what I ended up doing is hacking `sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py` and exporting the words and values as tuples for class CountVectorizer rather than just the words.

Comment: This is the method you would need to redo:https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L734   But can you please explain why do you want to do it? You can set the `max_df`, `min_df` accordingly to not remove those words.

Comment: Thanks, Vivek for the reply. Yes, I have read text.py and you are correct about the function. The reason I need this is not to get the best algorithmically possible features, but to introduce a human supervision on top of that by allowing my expert users to add ignored textual features from the, say, top 20 stopwords_.